# Is it possible for the system of equations of an electric circuit to not have a unique solution?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

When using Kirchhoff's circuit laws and Ohm's law to model the system of linear equations corresponding to an electric circuit (so far, circuits involving resistors and sources only), I haven't been able to find any circuit that yields an inconsistent system nor a system with infinite solutions.

Thus I was wondering if it were possible that the resulting system of equations didn't have an unique solution, and if so, what would be the physical interpretation for such a result?

Also, in case it is not possible, what would be the scientific result that supports that fact? For the sake of clarity, I attach an example of the kind of circuits I have been working with and its corresponding system of equations.

[image][image]

Comment: Do you permit negative resistances (multiple solutions may then exist)? What about the case of shorting a voltage source? Or opening a current source path? What about non-linear components and oscillation? What you are including and excluding in your question? Clearly, if you have the same number of variables as equations and the equations are independent and consistent and a determinant exists, then the solution will be unique. But that's just a mathy evasion. So look [here](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) at Section 9.4+ for one of many approaches.

Comment: Also, I was able to find [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150122071322/http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Etakis/L/Circuits/2000/handouts/graphsandckts/graphsandckts.pdf) using a few key search words and it looks closer to what I imagine you are looking for.

Comment: Include active devices like transistors and the answer is yes. A flip-flop for example has two stable solutions and some unstable ones. You're reading this comment on such a system. Just sources and resistors? No.

Comment: Infinite number of solutions: have in a network with 2 zero ohm branches in parallel with each other. Then any ratio between their currents can fulfill the laws as long as the sum of their currents is right. As well you can have a network which actually is 2 totally separate networks without any common node.. Then there can be any  voltage between the parts.  If you search for general electric network theory you will find how networks including the topology can be presented as matrices . That returns the problem to the existence and uniqueness of a linear matrix equation.

Comment: (continued) if you allow dependent voltage or current sources you can easily find circuits which cannot have any solution. Consider a source which has Uout=Uin+1V. Connect is Uout directry to its Uin. Then Uout=Uout+1V.

Answer (score 12):

So long as you consider networks containing only positive-valued linear resistors, ideal voltage sources, and ideal current sources (and you don't put two current sources in series or two voltage sources in parallel) there will always be a single unique solution.

I don't have a proof of this ready to hand, but it is pretty clear that if you follow the (modified) nodal analysis method you will obtain one equation for each node (other than the ground node) that isn't connected to a voltage source, and one KVL equation for each supernode, plus a supernode equation. And that these equations will be linearly independent because each node connects to a different set of branches. (A complementary argument showing a similar result for mesh analysis)

For a thorough proof, see, for example, [Chua, Desoer, and Kuh, 1987](https://b-ok.cc/book/881087/c57323).

If you consider nonlinear resistors, it is possible to have a circuit with multiple solutions. One way this happens is if the circuit has *hysteresis*, so that the correct physical solution depends on the history of how the source voltages were applied to get to the situation being analyzed.

Comment: did you leave capacitors and inductors out intentionally?

Comment: @relayman357, if we're talking about DC circuits, capacitors and inductors are just open circuits and wires.

Comment: Why limit the circuit to steady-state DC?  It isn’t necessary  as DC transient excitation, AC excitation etc. of R, L, C circuits still result in unique solutions for the specific conditions.

Comment: @relayman357, anyway I don't think it's true if we start talking about AC circuits with L and C elements. Suppose I have an AC current source. Across it I connect an LC series circuit at resonance (so net impedance is 0). And then in parallel with that I connect a second LC circuit at resonance. Now there's no unique solution for the current through either of the tanks.

Comment: I agree, mathematically.  But those are not real circuits.  A short across the terminals if an ideal voltage source would produce infinite current (and KVL violated) but that is impossible in real world.  Any tank circuit will have some resistance and will not be perfectly in resonance.  This is interesting topic.

Comment: @relayman357, sorry I edited my comment to specify a current source, not a voltage source. But in any case, this is a theory question, so we should consider those not-real-world circuits.

Comment: Yeah, agree. Plus, I looked back just now and OP limited to resistors anyway.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that Kirchoffs laws and the procedure to replace components with idealized versions is a model, and a procedure to assist in solvability.

As others have mentioned, hysteresis and oscillation are two scenarios where additional components even in their idealized form will lead to more complex models. uncontrolled feedback is a behavior that results from solutions that tend to infinity. You can also create circuits with infinite solutions such as this fractal oscillator: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02675. Even inconsistent/chaotic solutions are possible: http://www.chaotic-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Simple-Two-Transistor-Single-Supply-RC-Chaotic-Oscillator.pdf

But even considering the simple components you have here, you can consider the applicability of the model: its a steady state model - it does not say anything about circuit start up or shut down, more complex modeling would show interesting behaviour in these phases

So:

1. Yes its possible to have multiple solutions, solutions going to infinity and infinite solutions
2. It does have physical meaning in the behaviour of the circuit
3. simplified models are designed for solvability and can ignore more complex edge cases