# Existence and uniqueness of solutions to Thévenin circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

Suppose I have a circuit composed of ideal resistors, voltage sources and current sources, and Kirchoff's laws hold. The circuit can be solved using a system of linear equations derived from Kirchoff's laws. However, sometimes a solution might not exist. For example, if we short-circuit a voltage source, Kirchoff's voltage law fails on the short circuit.

As a person with a mathematical background, I am wondering the following:

1. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a solution?
2. Is the solution always unique?

Comment: I don't think you should be shorting voltage sources anyway. It means that there was no resistance so equivalent resistance is 0 and equivalent voltage is the source voltage. So it kind of still applies.

Comment: See if this [from yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/532914/204153) helps.

Comment: You can't say KVL'fails' when a voltage source is shorted because all voltage sources have an internal resitance in real life. If you argue with an ideal voltage source, KVL still doesn't fail, V/R=I becomes V/0=I, which is still true for this circuit. Mathematically, division by zero is 'undefined', so is the behavior of this ideal circuit. You can't say Math 'failed'. Can you?

Comment: I think you should start by providing mathematically rigorous definitions of "circuit" and "solved". It seems like you are playing pretty loose with those terms.

Comment: In this model I assume that all sources are ideal. I am not concerned with the real world. I told you I have a math background! To formalize the setup, let's say that the circuit is a bipartite graph where vertices on one side represent components and vertices on the other side represent nodes (in the sense of the node method of circuit analysis). Edges connect components to the adjacent nodes. Solving a circuit means finding a set of voltages for the nodes and currents for components that are consistent with KVL and KCL and the voltage and current sources.

Comment: The question from yesterday does help. Quite a coincidence that essentially the same question was asked just yesterday. It didn't show up on the search that I did.

Comment: If you short an ideal voltage source then you no longer have a valid circuit, so of course you can't analyze it properly. I think your question is circular.

Answer (score 1):

If the circuit is made up of ideal voltage sources, current sources, and resistors, then there will always be a unique solution. As you have said yourself, it creates a system of linear equations that can always be solved.

The example you give for shorting the voltage source with an ideal wire does not make sense as you will have conflicting definitions of the voltage at across/at the node. The voltage source defines a voltage (i.e. 1V) across it while the wire will define no voltage (i.e. 0V) across it. To give an example to you with a math background, this is equivalent as saying 1=0 which is just not true.

Comment: But not all systems of linear equations can be solved. If there are n unknowns, we need n linearly independent equations. How can we know we can always find those?

I see that shorting a voltage source contradicts either the ideality of the source or the wire. I think the interpretation here is just that the circuit is unsolvable. For an attempt to fully formalize the setup, see my comment on my original question.

Comment: If you have a circuit with n nodes, then you will have n unknown voltages and you will be able to construct n equations using nodal analysis. I don't have any formal proof but the linked question has a more in depth answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532914/is-it-possible-for-the-system-of-equations-of-an-electric-circuit-to-not-have-a?noredirect=1&lq=1