# Conditions for a resistive circuit to have a solution

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

I am looking for (sufficient and/or necessary) conditions for *a linear resistive circuit to have a solution*.

By "linear resistive circuit" I mean one which only contains ideal voltage and current sources and resistors with linear characteristic. I will be happy even with "independent ideal voltage and current sources" instead of "ideal voltage and current sources".

Searching in Stack Exchange (and, more generally the internet) I have found a few relevant links, e.g.,

[Is it possible for the system of equations of an electric circuit to not have a unique solution?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532914/is-it-possible-for-the-system-of-equations-of-an-electric-circuit-to-not-have-a)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742680/unique-solution-for-circuits-in-linear-algebra

but I believe the answers provided are incomplete / incorrect. For example, I see "So long as you consider networks containing only positive-valued linear resistors, ideal voltage sources, and ideal current sources (and you don't put two current sources in series or two voltage sources in parallel) there will always be a single unique solution." But this is contradicted by the following circuit which does not have a solution (unless \$V_1+V_2+V_3=0\$):

[image]

It is also easy to see **why** this circuit has no solution and how to produce many more similar examples.

Of course there is a "trivial" answer to my question: a linear resistive circuit \$C\$ has exactly one solution iff the  tableau matrix is invertible (it appears in Chua, Desoer and Kuh, p. 229). But if one sets up the tableau (or mesh, node etc. ) matrix and inverts it, then the answer is obvious. I am looking for some more "structural" or, at any rate, easier to evaluate conditions.

Any help wil be appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to just hand-wave towards the Rank-Nullity theorem, though that's a part of it. So instead, I'll direct you to Wai-Kai Chen's "Graph Theory and Its Engineering Applications", *Advanced Series in Electrical and Computer Engineering -- Vol 5*, Chapter 2, Section 7, pp. 125ff. 2.7 is titled ***The existence and uniqueness of the network solutions*** and provides significant historical references as well as this statement: *"For the system of equations to be consistent, it is necessary and sufficient that the coefficient matrix and the augmented matrix have the same rank."*

Comment: It makes total sense because of how the left and right nullspaces representing cases where KCL and KVL sum to zero. However, that statement comes ***after*** some other details, such as removing trivial equations. Context matters. But you will have all you need there. Just spend time on Chapter 2.

Comment: @periblepsis: Wai-Kai Chen is gold. And also the classic Sheshu and Reed. I will compose an answer based on these, but I need some help on the folowing point. It seems to me that, apart from the rather obvious theorems to the effect "there exists a unique solution if the such-and-such matrix is nonsingular", the available results provide *sufficient* conditions (see WKC Thm. 2.34 and SR Thm. 6-12). For necessary and sufficient conditions I only see WKC Thm.2.35 but I do not understand "imperfectly coupled" and, more importantly, does this theorem apply to purely resistive networks?

Comment: Yes, that text is gold. Just before theorem 2.35, in the paragraph immediately preceding, the author carefully defines *perfectly coupled* and then in the next sentence tells you that (unless otherwise stated) he will pursue the case where matrix ***L*** is nonsingular/positive definite (and *imperfect*.) This ***only*** applies to RLCM, where the author is *extending* earlier ideas. Since there's no need for ***s L*** in the impedance matrix if there are only resistors, the meaning of perfectly and imperfectly coupled disappears for obvious reasons. Use the earlier more prosaic discussion.

Comment: Yes, I understand all these things. For resistive networks the LCM part goes away. But then Thm.2.35 reduces to: "G has a unique solution iff there is no circuit ... generators." This gives a *necessary and sufficient condition* for solution uniqueness for resistive networks. But then why does  Thm.2.34 give *only a sufficient condition* for solution existence for resistive networks? SheshuReed Thm.6-12  similarly gives only a sufficient condition for for solution existence for resistive networks.

Comment: OK, I think the following works. Take a resistive network. (A) If  it does not contain any circuit (cut) consisting only of independent and dependent voltage (current) generators, then by Chen 2.34 it has a unique solution. (B) If it contains a circuit  consisting only of independent and dependent voltage generators, it has either no solution of an infinity of solutions, by the original counterexample. (C) Similar if it contains a cut consisting only of independent and dependent current generators. I think this works, if nothing new comes up I will write it up as an answer, soon.

Comment: Sounds good!! I'd like to read what you write!!! I'm very glad we find the same book to be enjoyable. I have very much appreciated finding it, some time ago. It's been a while. But I knew it was gold when I first skimmed it. It's good to hear you are finding it equally good! I have retained some things, forgotten others. But I know where to go when I need to refresh my thoughts. Best wishes to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question, as pointed out by [another user](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/330261) is given by the following Theorem, which is a paraphrase of Thm.2.35, p. 130 in Wai-Kai Chen's "Graph Theory and its Engineering Applications".

> **Theorem**. Let K be a circuit containing only resistors (of strictly positive resistance) independent ideal voltage sources and independent ideal current sources. Then K has exactly one solution if and only if there is no loop consisting only of voltage sources and no cutset  consisting only of current sources.

**Remarks**

1. The above mentioned Thm. 2.35 is more general: it refers to circuits which may also contain capacitors and inductors.
2. I have translated Chen's terms to more familiar EE terminology: for his "network" I wrote  "circuit", and for his "circuit" I wrote "loop". I actually prefer Chen's terminology.
3. The conditions of the Theorem are necessary. To see this consider the following circuits.

3.1 In the following circuit there exists a loop \$\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}\$ consisting only of voltage sources:

[image]

This circuit has no solution when \$V_1+V_2+V_3\ne 0\$ and an infinity of solutions when \$V_1+V_2+V_3 = 0\$

3.2 In the following circuit there exists a cutset \$\{I_1,I_2,I_3\}\$ consisting only of current sources:

[image]

This circuit has no solution when \$I_1+I_2+I_3\ne 0\$ and an infinity of solutions when \$I_1+I_2+I_3 = 0\$

3.2.1 The second example has an interesting history related to a paper by W. Marshall Leach Jr [On the Application of Superposition to Dependent Sources in Circuit Analysis](https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/papers/superpos.pdf). The linked pdf includes both the paper and the review by which it was rejected, because the proposed method could not solve the above circuit (with \$I_3\$ being a depndent source). Leach correctly observes that the method fails because the circuit is unsolvable (by any method).

4. In another related question [Unique solution for circuits in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742680/unique-solution-for-circuits-in-linear-algebra), an answer mentions the online book [Markov Chains and Mixing Times](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf)  where a connection is drawn between Markov chains, electrical circuits and potentials (see Section 9.3, pp.118-119). The **classic** work on this topic is [Random Walks and Electric Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001057.pdf). In short, existence and uniqueness of network solution follows from the fact that voltage is a *harmonic function* (also on a circuit).
5. Finally, it will be interesting and hard to find out what (if anything) *Kirchoff* had to say about existence / uniqueness  of solutions. His original 1847 paper can be found [here](https://ia600708.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/22/items/crossref-pre-1909-scholarly-works/10.1002%252Fandp.18471460122.zip&file=10.1002%252Fandp.18471481202.pdf). It is in German and, obviously, his terminology and style are very different from what we currently use. Still, it will be a hard fascinating  read!

Answer (score 5):

> and you don't put two current sources in series or two voltage sources in parallel

This condition should be rephrased as: "the circuit does not contain a zero-impedance loop with one or more voltage sources in it" (in other words, the circuit does not violate Kirchhoff's Voltage Law).

Two voltage sources in parallel is only a special case of this more general rule.

The example circuit contains a loop made of three voltage sources: if the sources are ideal, their internal impedance is zero, thus current will be infinite, so it is unsolvable. Unless V1+V2+V3=0, but even in this special case, you'll end up splitting hairs about the actual value of 0/0.

In the same vein, two current sources in series is a way to violate Kirchhoff's Current Law, but there are many others.

Comment: The quote from the OP should be "two or more", not just "two", and his circuit has three voltage sources in series.